# Set reminder to a task API Podio

Tags: php, podio

I try to set a reminder (30 minutes before due date) on a task created by the API based on doc examples: https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/create-task-with-reference-22420
https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/create-task-22419

Here's the code:

`PodioTask::create_for(
    'item',
    $order->item_id,
    array(
      'text'        => "Préparer la livraison de la commande",
      'description' => "Testing tasks",
      'responsible' => 00000,
      'due_date'    => date('Y-m-d'),
      'due_time'    => '09:00:00',
      'reminder'    => array('remind_delta' => 30)
    )
);`

Beside of the fact that the reminder is not set, the task is created with the provided information above. There is no error related to the API.

Is there something missing?

Comment: Can you please describe how you verify that reminder is not set? 
I've tried same method in Ruby and it works well:
  task_attr = {'text' => 'Task text', 'description' => 'Desc %)', 'due_date' => '2016-09-24', 'due_time' => '09:00:00',
               'reminder' => {'remind_delta' => 30}}
  task = Podio::Task.create_with_ref('item', 484007743, task_attr)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but I finally figured it out.  See below:

```
PodioTask::create_for(
    'item',
    $item_id,
    $attributes = array (
    'text' => $item_id,
    'private' => true,
    'due_date' => $appt_date,
    'due_time' => $appt_time,
    'responsible' => 1234567, // User ID
    'reminder' => (object)[
        'remind_delta' => 0
        ]
    )
);
```

For my purposes the user will always be the same, so I set that as static.

**BE AWARE**  You MUST authenticate with the API using the users credentials that the reminder is being set for.  It WILL NOT set a reminder for another user (partially why I'm using a static user).

**EDIT** Since I don't have enough reputation points, I want to call out [Pavlo - Podio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6495121/pavlo-podio)

1. One can verify if a reminder is set by looking at it in Podio.  It's pretty simple, either there's a reminder set or there's not.
2. The OP, and myself, aren't using Ruby, so whether Ruby works or not is irrelevant to the problems we're facing.

While I realize you were trying to help.  The fact that you're a "Test Automation Engineer at Podio" raises the expectation that you COULD provide useful information.  So pull out the PHP and see what we're experiencing.